# Nuxt - Using router.push inside a component not changing pages correctly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router

index.vue -

```
<template>
<div>
    <Header />
    <div class="container">
        <SearchForm />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
const Cookie = process.client ? require('js-cookie') : undefined

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: ''
            },
            show: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        logout() {
            // Code will also be required to invalidate the JWT Cookie on external API
            Cookie.remove('auth')
            this.$store.commit('setAuth', {
                auth: null,
                user_type: null
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.container {
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    /* min-height: 100vh; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

jobs.vue -

```
<template>
<div>
    <Header />
    <SearchForm />
    <b-container class="main_container">
        <b-row>
        <h1> Results for "{{q}}"</h1>
        </b-row>
        <b-row>
        <ul id="array-rendering">
            <li v-for="item in results" :key="item.job_id">
                {{ item.job_title }}
                {{ item.job_city }}
                {{ item.job_state }}
                {{ item.job_work_remote }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
const Cookie = process.client ? require('js-cookie') : undefined
export default {
    // middleware: 'notAuthenticated',
    watchQuery: ['q'],
    data() {
        return {
            q: null,
            results: []
        }
    },
    async fetch() {
        this.q = this.$route.query.q
        this.results = await this.$axios.$get('/api/job/search', {
            params: {
                keyword: this.q,
            }
        })
    },

    methods: {

    }
}
</script>

<style>
.container {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

SearchForm.vue component -

```
<template>
<div id='searchFormDiv'>
    <b-form inline @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inline-form-input-name"> keyword</label>
        <b-form-input v-model="form.keyword" id="inline-form-input-name" class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Job title or keyword" size="lg"></b-form-input>

        <label class="sr-only" for="inline-form-input-username">location</label>
        <b-input-group class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
            <b-form-input v-model="form.location" id="inline-form-input-username" size="lg" placeholder="City, state or zip"></b-form-input>
        </b-input-group>

        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Find Jobs</b-button>
    </b-form>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import {
    BIconSearch,
    BIconGeoAlt
} from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                keyword: '',
                location: ''
            }
        }
    }, 
    created () {
        this.form.keyword = this.$route.query.q
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            this.$router.push({
                path: 'jobs',
                query: {
                    q: this.form.keyword
                }
            });
        }
    },
    components: {
        BIconSearch,
        BIconGeoAlt
    },
}
</script>

<style>
#searchFormDiv {
    margin-top: 50px
}
</style>
```

The route for "http://localhost:3000/" returns the `index.vue` page.

In this vue page, I have a component with a search form. Once you complete these form and hit the seach button, it will re-direct to a results page

if `this.form.keyword = "Data"`, the next URL will be "http://localhost:3000/jobs?q=Data" and it will be using the `jobs.vue` page.

The issue I'm running into is the CSS is not being loaded from the `jobs.vue` page. It's still coming from the `index.vue` page for some reason. If I refresh the page, then the CSS from `jobs.vue` is loading. I need the CSS to load from `jobs.vue` on the initial redirect. All of the query data is working as expected so thats a plus.

However, the following CSS is being applied from `index.vue` for some reason instead of the CSS from the `jobs.vue` page -

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Does anyone know whats going on here? This app is SSR and not SPA.

Comment: try adding !important for both the lines
eg: display: flex !important;

Comment: @Amaarrockz the issue is the CSS is being loaded from index.vue instead of jobs.vue after I do router.push.

Comment: then yo need to share some more detail...can you share the index.vue and jobs.vue

Comment: have your declare your CSS with the "scoped" directive ? https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

Comment: @Amaarrockz code for pages.vue, index.vue and SearchForm.vue have been added to the quesion

Comment: @NicolasPennec so I think scoped would only apply to an SPA app. I'm using a SSR Nuxt app so it should use the jobs.vue page on router.push

Answer (score 1):

You have to scope your css from the `index.vue` page to the other pages with the `scoped` directive (see docs https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html)

```html
<style scoped>
/* local styles */
</style>

<style>
/* global styles */
</style>
```

You can add your global CSS in your `layouts/default.vue` file.

Comment: Thats not really the issue. index.vue and jobs.vue are both seperate pages. When I do router.push, I want to only load the jobs.vue template. This works if I refresh the page after the redirect. I need the router.push to have that same behavior.

Comment: That really is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue -

```
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        window.location = 'http://localhost:3000/jobs?q=' + this.form.keyword;
    }
},
```